# Strange characters in Javascript causing it to not load

Tags: javascript, encoding

My site works fine on localhost, my javascript is loading and working fine. But when I deploy the site the script is not working. When I right click the page and say view source and then view the linked script file, it has some strange characters at the start of the file **ï»¿**(function($){

On localhost, my script file starts like this `(function($){`

What is causing these characters to be prepended to my javascript file?

Comment: I wonder if the characters might be the Unicode leader?

Comment: @Pointy: They are.  That’s the UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: You say your script is not working.  That’s not very specific.  What error are you getting?  What did you expect to happen, but didn’t?  What do the Javascript Console, Firebug, Javascript Debugger and such tools report?

Answer (score 6):

You have to re-save the file in encoding "UTF-8 without BOM".
You can use Notepad++ or other editors.

In visual studio:

> By default, Visual Studio uses UTF encoding with the BOM; however, you can save it to a different encoding if you'd prefer.  When you go to the Save As dialog, you can expand the Save button to see the 'Save with Encoding' option.  This will prompt you for a different encoding, and I think one of the Unicode options will leave out the BOM (somewhere in the list is UTF-8 without signature).

Source: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/144306.aspx

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I'm using Visual Studio, surely there shouldn't be an issues with files saved with vs? Anyway I opened the file in notepad and saved it, there was no ï»¿ in the file, then I reupped it using filezilla. Still same issue...

Comment: I doubt that these characters are the reason of the script’s failure.  Most browsers know what to do with a UTF-8 BOM when they see it.  Also, OP says that they’re not visible when run on localhost, which suggests that it’s only Notepad who doesn’t interpret them.  Ergo, the script problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Martijn, ï»¿ is cleary the BOM squence, and if it shows up somewhere, it still can cause lots of problems.

Comment: @Martijn, by somewhere I mean in the browser, and that cleary happens in OP problem when it shows up in "View source".

Comment: @Briedis: Nope, it doesn’t.  "View Source" in IE will open Notepad.

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this same problem, and have found a fix.

As an answer to Martjin's question, the problem is that these URF-8 BOM characters invalidate the javascript when the client is expecting pure ASCII.  So it will say there is an error at char 1, line 1 or some such, basically, right at the beginning of the file because it makes the codefile look like there's a typo in the first few bytes of the script.

In my case, I have a Site in IIS that is an ASP.NET app, and an Application underneath it that is also an ASP.NET app.  This had caused some complications with inheriting web.configs, and the solution was to put a  tag that negates inheritance from that point on.

I then discovered that all my .js in the child site was throwing an error for that stupid UTF-8 encoding symbol that was the first 3 bytes of every file.  I am reasonably confident, that it is caused by some confusion in the httphandlers from my 2-tier solution for web.configs.

My solution, however was to convert the .js files back to pure ASCII, as that's what IIS was sending out and the client was expecting.  For me, I have a build.bat that copies all the web files, removes any source control and project files and puts them all in a final build directory for copying to the test or production server.  I made a modification to that script to also convert all the .js files to ASCII format.

It uses a combination of DOS batch (because that's where I started) and PowerShell (because that's the only way I found to convert without adding even more utility programs):

set DIRTOCONVERT=whatever path you want it to convert all the files for
ECHO remove UTF-8 BOM chars ï»? from front of files
for /r %DIRTOCONVERT% %%g in (*.js) do (
    powershell -command "gc -en utf8 \"%%g\" | Out-File -en ascii .\tmp.txt"
    move /y .\tmp.txt "%%g"
)

Note, a few people online (even in StackOverflow) had the idea to try:
type badfile.txt > goodfile.txt

but that still carries over the UTF-8 encoding.  Apparently, it did not used to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think Briedis is right about the problem, but I suggest a different solution.

When you serve the file, is it being served with a `Content-type` like

```
Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=US-ASCII
```

?

If so, make sure to serve it with a charset of UTF-8 instead.

Comment: It would be very nice to mention how to do just that.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks, without knowing anything about your server, I can't.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and found the fix when stumbling on this thread.

There was indeed a problem with the files not being UTF-8 (without BOM), but re-saving my js files as utf-8 didn't work, instead, it was my HTML file that imported these scripts that was the culprit. After I saved that file as UTF-8, the issue was resolved.

Comment: I just ran into this problem, illegal characters in JS files displayed as Chinese characters by the browser debug tools. (I un-minified and separated to narrow the problem down) and the culprit was indeed my html which for some as yet undiscovered, had a UCS-2 LE BOM encoding. Changing that to UTF-8 resolved the issue. Chrome proved more useful than Firefox finding out what was going on.