# jQuery/javascript not working on all pages

Tags: javascript

So I'm doodling with a little site with some html/css/javascript experiments so I can learn to be a better web-programmer. I am really a designer, and total n00b at this.

**Problem:**

I have some javaScript running on multiple pages at my site, and they are – as per usual – in a seperate .js-file. However it only seems to be working on this page:

http://www.carlpapworth.com/htmlove/colors.html

And not on these:

http://www.carlpapworth.com/htmlove/arrows.html

http://www.carlpapworth.com/htmlove/fumbling.html

U see, the big splash with the heart is suposed to be hidden by this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#reward').hide();
    $('#goal a').click(function(){
        $('#reward').fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $('.exit').click(function(){
        $('#collection1').css('color', '#ff63ff');
     });
});
```

To me, the "Head"-code in all these pages looks exactly the same, so I can't figure out the problem.
Please help!

**SOLVED!** It was the encoding, that was set to UTF-16! So I just changed it as Jezen Thomas said in Coda! Thanks a million!

Comment: What's with all the Chinese characters in the console?

Comment: I think the problem maybe something to do with character-encoding/BOM.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that also (the chinese) it is most weird!

Comment: what does "character-encoding/BOM" mean, and is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting question. I tried copying your site to my machine and testing locally, and everything worked just fine. However, I believe I've discovered the source of the problem.

http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/check?uri=www.carlpapworth.com%2Fhtmlove%2Ffumbling.html#validate-by-uri+

You're trying to force UTF-8 with your meta tag, `<meta charset='UTF-8' />`. However, the w3 i18n validator detected that your file also contains a [UTF-16LE Byte-Order Mark (BOM)](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark).

The w3 has this to say on [removing the BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom):

> If you have an editor which shows the characters that make up the
>   UTF-8 signature you may be able to delete them by hand. Chances are,
>   however, that the BOM is there in the first place because you didn't
>   see it.
>
> Check whether your editor allows you to specify whether a UTF-8
>   signature is added or kept during a save. Such an editor provides a
>   way of removing the signature by simply reading the file in then
>   saving it out again. For example, if Dreamweaver detects a BOM the
>   Save As dialogue box will have a check mark alongside the text
>   "Include Unicode Signature (BOM)". Just uncheck the box and save.

I'm not sure if it'll fix the problem in your case, but I don't like the fact that you've used HTML comments before your doctype declaration. Please move `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of the file. Also, in Coda, go to `Text > Encoding` and verify that UTF-8 is selected. If you can, show the invisible characters and remove anything that looks suspect.

Comment: Ok this is a bit out of my league :) I use Coda however, and what is this "BOM"?

Comment: Still wierd that it works on one page and not the other, I'll try and fix with it. The comments aspect seems reasonable :)

SOLVED! It was the encoding, that was set to UTF-16! So I just changed it as Jezen Thomas said in Coda! Thanks a million!

Comment: Im new to this, and guessing that it is the green "tick"!

Comment: Yes, it's the green tick. You selected the other answer as correct, not mine :)

Comment: Sorry, thought u could select more than one ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Jezen Thomas suggested, it may be an encoding issue. Try re-saving the file as UTF-8.

Check out [this topic on SO for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434748/strange-characters-in-javascript-causing-it-to-not-load).

Comment: @CarlPapworth There's more to it than that. Check my answer.

Comment: The .js file itself needs to be encoded properly - the .html page works as expected, but the .js files are your issue.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby Actually it was the .html files that was the issue, they where saved as UTF-16.